# UE4 ALS v4 How to use anim montage with curves?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I try to use reload anim montage from anim starter pack in ALS v4.
I added ArmR ArmL and Curves slots in anim montage, but now appears stranje jerking at start an end of animation

Comment: You'll probably need to contact the plugin developer(s) and or ask on the unreal forum (probably with concise steps to reproduce).

Answer (score 0):

found answer there, i set curves in anim montag instead animation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DR2uZUc8E5g